# Twiml Dial CallStatus always "ringing" even if callee is disconnected

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to make Client to Client in my App using Twilio Programmable Voice with scenario:

1. Caller makes call request via  "/makecall" API.
2. Mobile App set state "connecting"
3. If Mobile App receives "ringing" state from Twilio SDK, it starts playing "ringing" sound.
4. If Mobile App receives "connection failure" instead, it shows "can't connect"
5. If Mobile App receives "connected", it stops "ringing" sounds and start the timer

But it looks like Twilio always return "ringing" even when callee is disconnected (I turn off the network or even uninstall the app)

My Server /makecall function:

```
        dial := &twiml.VoiceDial{}
    client := &twiml.VoiceClient{
        Identity:             to,
        StatusCallbackEvent:  "initiated ringing answered completed",
        StatusCallback:       "https://mydemo.app/callstatus",
        StatusCallbackMethod: "POST",
    }
    dial.AnswerOnBridge = "true"
    dial.CallerId = from
    dial.InnerElements = []twiml.Element{client}
    verbList := []twiml.Element{dial}
    twimlResult, err := twiml.Voice(verbList)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    return twimlResult
```

The /callstatus is called 3 times with the following parameter data:

First it was initiated

```
ApiVersion  "2010-04-01"
Called  "client:Callee1"
ParentCallSid   "CA6fe3xxx"
CallStatus  **"initiated"**
From    "client:Caller1"
Direction   "outbound-dial"
Timestamp   "Sun, 23 Apr 2023 04:01:16 +0000"
AccountSid  "ACaxxx"
CallbackSource  "call-progress-events"
Caller  "client:Caller1"
SequenceNumber  "0"
CallSid "CA306daxxx"
To  "client:Callee1"
```

Second callstatus callback:

```
ApiVersion  "2010-04-01"
Called  "client:Callee1"
ParentCallSid   "CA6fexxx"
CallStatus  **"ringing"**
From    "client:Caller1"
Direction   "outbound-dial"
Timestamp   "Sun, 23 Apr 2023 04:01:17 +0000"
AccountSid  "ACa19740xxx"
CallbackSource  "call-progress-events"
Caller  "client:Caller1"
SequenceNumber  "1"
CallSid "CA306xxx"
To  "client:Callee1"
```

Final callstatus callback:

```
ApiVersion  "2010-04-01"
Called  "client:Callee1"
ParentCallSid   "CA6xxx3"
CallStatus  **"no-answer"**
Duration    "0"
From    "client:Caller1"
Direction   "outbound-dial"
CallDuration    "0"
Timestamp   "Sun, 23 Apr 2023 04:01:23 +0000"
AccountSid  "ACa1xxx"
CallbackSource  "call-progress-events"
SipResponseCode "487"
Caller  "client:Caller1"
SequenceNumber  "2"
CallSid "CA3xxx"
To  "client:Callee1"
```

Wonder why CallStatus return "ringing" if callee is disconnected?

Trying to handle call flow on Mobile app using Twilio SDK

Comment: Please provide more info. The three callback examples you provided seem to show the behavior your want. Ringing is only shown in the second example.

Comment: The behavior I expected when callee disconnected is "connection failed". Digging into logs, it looks like "ringing" status belongs to the first call leg, while we need to monitor the second call leg.